# How can I avoid duplicate cards in my Blackjack game?

Tags: java

I've writing a blackjack game, comprised of an enum of Suits, objects of CardValues, whose constructors and instance variables are:

```
public class CardValue{

    private String face;
    private int numeric;


    public CardValue(String faceVal){
        face = faceVal;
        numeric = findNumericVal(faceVal);
    }...}
```

and cards determined as:

```
public class Card{

  private CardValue value;
  private Suit suit;

  public Card(){
    this.value = new CardValue(determineFace());
    this.suit = determineSuit();

  }

  public static Suit determineSuit(){

    int randNum = (int) (Math.random() * 4);

    if (randNum == 0){
      return Suit.CLUBS;
    }
    else if (randNum == 1){
      return Suit.DIAMONDS;
    }
    else if (randNum == 2){
      return Suit.HEARTS;
    }
    else{ 
      return Suit.SPADES;
    }

  public static String determineFace(){
    String f = null;

    int rand = (int)(Math.random()*13);

    if (rand == 0){
      f = "2";
    }
    if (rand == 1){
      f = "3";
    }
    if (rand == 2){
      f = "4";
    }
    if(rand == 3){
      f = "5";
    }
    if(rand == 4){
      f = "6";
    }
    if(rand == 5){
      f = "7";
    }
    if(rand == 6){
      f = "8";
    }
    if(rand == 7){
      f = "9";
    }
    if(rand == 8){
      f = "10";
    }
    if (rand == 9){
      f = "J";
    }
    if (rand == 10){
      f = "Q";
    }
    if (rand == 11){
      f = "K";
    }
    if(rand == 12){
      f = "A";
    }
    return f;

  }    

}
```

and I'm coming up on the issue of my player getting duplicate cards in the game. Instead of building a deck, I decided to make card randomly determined and use logical booleans to prevent duplicates. My dealIn(...) method in a CardGame class I made is:

```
  public static ArrayList<Card> dealIn(ArrayList<Card> hand){

    Card a = new Card();
    Card b = new Card();

    hand.add( a);

    if(!b.equals(a))
      hand.add(b);

    return hand;
  }
```

and its producing duplicates. How can I stop that?

Comment: You never implemented the equals method on your Card class...

Comment: I do have a getValue() method in it and a toString() method in it. I thought using "param1.equals(param2)" would check the contents of such Card objects.

Comment: What @cricket_007 said. You absolutely need to implement both `public boolean equals(Object o)` and `public int hashCode()` in your Card class. This is ***essential***.

Comment: should I then add an equals method to CardValue, seeing as Card takes a CardValue in the constructor?

Comment: `Instead of building a deck,` - why? You just add each Card to an ArrayList and then invoke the Collections.shuffle(...) and you have a deck of cards ready to deal.

Comment: in that case, I have in my Card class:                                                 
    `public boolean equals(Card c){
    if((value == c.value) && (suit == c.suit)){
      return true;
    }
    else{
      return false;
    }    
  }`

Comment: and I'm still getting duplicates!

Comment: Your `dealIn` method is confusing. I would at least do something like `while(b.equals(a)) { b = new Card();}` to ensure you get a unique 2nd card.

Comment: should I use the equals method in my Card class, or the java library one? I tried to use the one in my Card class, as in (!b.Card.equals(a)) and I get a compiler error.

Comment: CardValue and Suit classes also need equals and hashcode implementations. Also use equals(), not == for objects

Comment: I used equals() and it said, as this: if(!b.Card.equals(a)) bc the equals method I made is in the Card class and it says: "cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Card
  location: variable b of type Card" In my CardValue class, I now have the instance variables protected instead of private, which I did to test out the equals method I made (bc it allowed me to set values manually)

Comment: and it won't let me put @Override before my equals method

Comment: `b.equals()` not `b.Card.equals()`.

Comment: and I don't need to @Override (which I cannot in my Card class bc I get a compiler error) or write an equals method that uses Objects as parameters?

Answer (score 1):

I would make a `LinkedList<Card>` called `deck` to represent the entire deck. In Blackjack the dealer mixes several standard decks into one big deck. Generate *n* (where n is the number of standard decks in in the big deck) `Card`'s for every card in a standard deck and add it to `deck`. Then do
`Collections.shuffle(deck);` This shuffles your `LinkedList` called `deck`. Then to draw a card do `deck.poll()` which returns the top `Card` from `deck` and removes it from `deck`.

Here's the problem with your RNG method: Even in single player Blackjack there are several cards dealt per round. The minimum number is 4 (2 for dealer, 2 for player), but if either the player or dealer hits you could be looking at way more cards dealt during one round. Therefore it would be too inconvenient too randomly generate cards and check if each one matches one of the previously dealt cards. **Besides, as I said, in real Blackjack, you have a big deck comprised of standard decks, so there will be duplicates.**

Comment: I'm looking to do single deck; I feel I learn the most from it.

Comment: Well, even if you do that, you still have the issue that you have to make sure that none of the cards are duplicates, not just the two cards in the player's hand.

Comment: Single or multiple decks, you will need the full set of cards and shuffle them. This answer even gives you the option to do both. Great answer